# Change flutter generated localizations files directory

Tags: flutter, localization

is there a way to change the directory that contains all the generated files about localization?
When I run the app they are automatically generated in .dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n and I want to change it.

(directory photo) https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjqHp.png

This is my l10n.yaml:

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-files: app_localizations.dart # auto generated
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Need to add both `output-dir` and `synthetic-package` parameters.

This is my l10n.yaml

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: s.dart
output-class: S
output-dir: lib/l10n
synthetic-package: false
```

Run `flutter gen-l10n` to generate file

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the output of:

```
flutter gen-l10n --help
```

Normally, you can put any of these parameters in l10n.yaml

I have not tried, tell me if it is ok !

I think **output-dir** parameter will help