# Flutter Intl plugin – how to set location of l10n directory that is generated?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-localizations, flutter-intl

I'm trying to use the `flutter_intl` plugin for Android Studio with an add-to-app Flutter app I'm developing on Android (by which I mean the Flutter app exists within an Android app, in its own sub-directory, and the Android Studio project includes all the Android code as well.) The issue is when I initialise `flutter_intl` it creates the `l10n` folder at the base of the Android directory, not further down the tree where Flutter's `lib` folder actually is. Is it possible to specify in `flutter_intl` where the `l10n` folder should be, rather than it being automatically generated within a new `lib` folder at the root?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `l10n.yaml` file at the root directory and put this in the file:

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
output-dir: l10n
```

Change the directory according to your needs.

change `arb-dir` for translations files directory and `output-dir` for output files.

Run `flutter gen-l10n --help` command, parameters listed can be used in `l10n.yaml` file

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71401194/8807231

Comment: thanks, but will this change the place Flutter Intl initialises files and treats as the location to add extracted strings and locales that I add? It doesn't seem to be affecting how that plugin itself works